# How to use two conditions in "where" clause in XQuery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

I'm trying to extract only those `<book>` data that has a certain type of `<xref>` type and matching a list of specific xrefs using a Xquery (I'm new to this).

Here is the input data:

```
  <book id="6636551">
    <master_information>
        <book_xref>
            <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">72771KAM3</xref>
            <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US72771KAM36</xref>
        </book_xref>
    </master_information>
  </book>
  <book id="119818569">
    <master_information>
        <book_xref>
            <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">070185UL5</xref>
            <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US070185UL50</xref>
        </book_xref>
    </master_information>
  </book>
  <book id="119818568">
  <master_information>
        <book_xref>
            <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">070185UK7</xref>
            <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US070185UK77</xref>
        </book_xref>
    </master_information>
  </book>
  <book id="119818567">
    <master_information>
        <book_xref>
            <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">070185UJ0</xref>
            <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US070185UJ05</xref>
        </book_xref>
    </master_information>
  </book>
  <book id="38085123">
    <master_information>
        <book_xref>
            <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">389646AV2</xref>
            <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US389646AV26</xref>
        </book_xref>
    </master_information>
  </book>
```

XQuery that I'm using:

```
for $x in //book 
where $x//xref/@type='Fiction'
and
$x//xref=('070185UL5','070185UJ0')
return $x
```

The above Xquery only fetches the first book information matching the "070185UL5". I would expect it to fetch both. What is wrong? I appreciate your response.

Comment: It does fetch both.

Comment: It looks fine to me and works when testing with Saxon. Maybe try changing your where clause to `where $x//xref[@type='Fiction'][normalize-space()=('070185UL5','070185UJ0')]`.

Comment: I'm sorry. It does fetch both when I tried again now. I don't know why it wasn't working before. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the query

```
for $x in //book 
where $x//xref/@type='Fiction'
and
$x//xref=('070185UL5','070185UJ0')
return $x
```

do you intend to say

(1) "there must be at least one xref whose @type is 'Fiction' and at least one xref whose value is '070185UL5' or'070185UJ0'"

or do you intend to say

(2) "there must be at least one xref whose @type is 'Fiction' and whose value is '070185UL5' or'070185UJ0'"

Currently you are saying (1). If you want to say (2) then the query should be

```
for $x in //book 
where $x//xref[@type='Fiction' and .=('070185UL5','070185UJ0')]
return $x
```

which you can simplify to the XPath expression

```
//book[.//xref[@type='Fiction' and .=('070185UL5','070185UJ0')]]
```

With the data you have supplied the two queries give the same result, but with different data they could give different results.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your input! I didn't think of it like that. I intend to say "Show me only 'Fiction' type whose xref equal to '070185UL5' or '070185UJ0' ". Although, I get mostly what you're saying, I don't understand on how to differentiate on this subtle difference of "at least" vs "show only". How does one enforce that in XQuery? (sorry, I'm new to this).

Comment: This isn't really specific to XQuery, it's basic boolean logic. There's a difference between "parents who have a child attending school and a child who is disabled" and "parents who have a disabled child who is attending school".